# How would I use "foreach" instead of "for" loop for this case?

Tags: php, loops, foreach

I want to make a loop to display each category and all sub-categories. I have this array:

```
$Allcategories = array(
  array(
    array("Category 1", 'category1'),
    array("Sub 1", 'sub1'),
    array("Sub 2", 'sub2'), 
    array("Sub 3", 'sub3') 
  ),
  array(
      array("Category 2", 'category2'),
      array("Sub 1", 'sub1'),
      array("Sub 2", 'sub2'), 
      array("Sub 3", 'sub3')
    )
);
```

I already made a 3-nest-for loop that works but I would like to simplify it with a `foreach`.
Here is my <del>`for`</del> loop:

```
foreach ($Allcategories as $val_1)
{    
    echo "<a href='index.php?category=", $val_1[0][1], "'>", $val_1[0][0], "</a>";    
    foreach ($val_1 as $val_2)
    {    
        foreach ($val_2 as $val_3)
        {
            printf('<li><a href="index.php?category=%1$s">%1$s</a><br />', $val_3);
        }    
    }    
}
```

The problem is I'm getting this result:

```
Category 1

    -Category 1

    -category1

    -Sub 1

    -sub1

    -Sub 2

    -sub2
```

---

Comment: I indented the original array so it's more visible that the depth changes. You need to deal with these depth-changes within your code otherwise it will not output the expected data.

Comment: Oh ok thanks a lot, I see better now. I deleted that unwanted array for second category. I still get Category 1, then category1, then Sub 1, then sub1.. Very confusing.

Answer (score 2):

The inner loops shouldn't iterate over `$Allcategories`, but rather, over the values from the outer loops:

```
foreach ($Allcategories as $layerNum => $layer) {
    ...
    foreach ($layer as $rowNum => $row) {
        ...
        foreach ($row as $colNum => $category) {
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for your response. I have edited my original post with the outcome. Please let me know if you know what is wrong. Thanks a lot regards

Answer (score 0):

Although you should write it as **ruakh** has shown, it might be useful to know that the problem with your code is that you're forgetting to reference `$key3`. It should be:

```
echo "<li><a href='index.php?category=".$Allcategories[$key1][$key2][$key3]
[1]."'>".$Allcategories[$key1][$key2][$key3][0]."</a><br />";
```

Edit: Or better yet, the whole thing:

```
foreach ($Allcategories as $val_1)
{

  echo "<a href='index.php?category=" . $val_1[0][1] . "'>" . $val_1[0][0] . "</a>";

  foreach ($val_1 as $val_2)
  {

    foreach ($val_2 as $val_3)
    {
      echo "<li><a href='index.php?category=" . $val_3[1] . "'>" . $val_3[0] . "</a><b></li>";
    }

  }

}
```

I've also taken the liberty or removing the `<br />` and instead closed the `<li>` as I believe that's what you want?

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for your response. I think it's $Allcategories[$key1][$key2][$key3], because with the [0], it ends up just showing the first letter of each element.

Comment: I have tried your code but it show Sub 1, then sub1, then Sub 2, then sub2. I am trying to modify it right now.

Comment: Can you show us the output of `print_r($Allcategories);` please?

Comment: Hi, I copy pasted the array at the beginning of original post. I also modified the original post to show the output of my loop. It repeats each element twice, which is quite confusing..

Comment: The array as given in the OP is not correct. Can you show us the exact output of `echo '<pre>' . print_r($Allcategories, true) . '</pre>';`

Comment: I think something is wrong with the two inner foreach. Because the outer one displays the Category 1 properly

Comment: Oh there was a bracket missing, when I copypasted into the OP. I put the output above

Comment: The problem is your array, as given in the OP. After adding the missing ')' to make it valid I can see that the second category is two levels deeper in the array than the first category making it a mess.

Comment: Ah.. this is quite confusing because it seems to me that the categories are on the same level.. Im trying to figure out what's wrong.. Thanks a lot